# Files just creating once on Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, storage, android-11

i have an app that take some pictures and print some logs with the logback-android library, this pictures and logs was saved in a folder in the root directory storage/emulated/0/my-directory/
But we are updating to Android 11 and the new storage policy dont let me save files in that route, so my pictures and logs are now stored in documents in this way:

```
val directory = File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "pictures")
if(directory.exists()) directory.deleteRecursively()                                                
fileName = this.getFileName(c);
File file = new File(directory, fileName);
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
output.write(data);
output.flush();
LOGGER.debug("File {} written", fileName);
output.close();
```

And the logback configuration looks like this:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        
    <file>/storage/emulated/0/documents/logs_proyect/log_proyect.txt</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
</appender>
```

The problem is that the files get saved correctly just once, if i delete the log file it stops writting logs forever, and even if i dont delete the file sometimes tops writting in it, and the same pass with the pictures, if i delete files it stop saving them.
I cant use the all files acces permission for the google policy, my manifest have this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You create files with new FileOutputStream. That has nothing to do with any logger. So i dont understand which problem you have.

Comment: the log files doesn't write if i delete the file once, example:
-I use the app an the logs start recording
-i delete the log file
-i use the app again but the logs doesn't record anymore

Comment: But why did you post code to create those other files? And where is the code of the logger? I cannot follow you.

Comment: If you cannort create picture files again then there should be an exception or other error. Please tell.

Comment: We dont see you creating directory "pictures". And are you deleting it recursively? Like the one for the logger?

Comment: Who is creating folder /storage/emulated/0/documents/logs_proyect ? And when? Are you deleting it?

Comment: i post the code of the other files because sometimes when i delete a picture it stops creating more, the logger that i use is the one from this library:
    log4j = 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
    logback_core = 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-3'
    logback_classic = 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-3'

Comment: Why dont you answer my comments? Please post a decent link for the logger.

Comment: sorry my fault: https://github.com/tony19/logback-android

Answer (score 1):

Starting Android 11 we have to use Scoped Storage or MediaStore APIs
Below is the link which explains how to use MediaStore Apis

https://gist.github.com/fiftyonemoon/433b563f652039e32c07d1d629f913fb

Answer (score 0):

Use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: i cant, because a google policy, if i use that permission i cant upload to playstore

Comment: any solution for this issue, am also facing the same